# Template functor and class template parameter deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to implement a class which is an iterator across a linked-list. I want to templatize it so you can construct it with a functor to determine when we are iterating to the end, but I can't get the class constructor template deduction to deduce the type of the functor.

A reduced example of what I'm trying to do:

```cpp
#include <utility>

struct A {};
struct B : A {};

template<typename T, typename F>
struct C
{
    A * a_;
    F f_;

    C(A * a, F && f) : a_(a), f_(std::move(f)) {}
    T & operator*() { return static_cast<T &>(*a_); }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    C<B> foo(&b, [b]() -> bool { return false; }); // error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
    return 0;
}
```

I always get the template argument error when trying to instantiate an object (compiling with c++17), strangely godbolt gives me these cryptic ones too: `error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]` and `error: cannot convert 'main()::<lambda()>' to 'int' in initialization` which makes no sense, but might just be fallout from the first error.

Shouldn't it be able to deduce the functor type `F` from the constructor arguments? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: [Quoth cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction): "Class template argument deduction is only performed if no template argument list is present. If a template argument list is specified, deduction does not take place." This means you can't specify some arguments and let others be deduced - you must specify all, or specify none and have all of them deduced.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik really? I thought as long as all the deduced types are _after_ the specified types in the template parameter list then it should work?

Comment: It works this way for function template argument deduction, but apparently not for class template. For the latter, it's all or nothing. This is easy to see in action: `std::pair p{1, 2};` compiles, but `std::pair<int> p{1,2};` does not.

Comment: Damn, thanks for the link...yeah that is buried down in the notes there. The first line of the page sure does seem to imply the usage of partial specification: "In order to instantiate a class template, every template argument must be known, but not every template argument has to be specified."

Comment: I guess in this case I can just make the first template argument deducible as well, that's easy enough

Comment: Or make a "make_c" function that constructs your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CTAD to work you can't supply any of the template parameters and since `T` can't be deduced, you need to supply the second template parameter too (that is, no CTAD).

Example:

```
auto l = [b]() -> bool { return false; };
C<B,decltype(l)> foo(&b, std::move(l));
```

You could add a helper function template though:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
auto C_creator(A* a, F&& f) { return C<T,F>(a, std::forward<F>(f)); }

auto foo = C_creator<B>(&b, [b]() -> bool { return false; });
```

Or change the constructor to take a `T*` instead of an `A*` so that `T` can be deduced.

```
C(T* a, F&& f) : a_(a), f_(std::move(f)) {}

auto foo = C(&b, [b]() -> bool { return false; });
```

Comment: The hope here is to _not_ have to specify all the types. In the comments above it seems class template deduction is all or nothing

Comment: @ZoltanDeWitt Yes, and since each lambda gets a unique type, this is how that would be solved.

Comment: In this case, I think it's easier to modify the constructor so it can deduce the first type as well. `decltype` works, but it makes the instantiation site a lot more verbose.

Comment: @ZoltanDeWitt Sure, if that's an option. I added that as well.

Comment: The important point I was missing is from Igor's comment above...that class template deduction is not like function template deduction: you must supply all parameters or none of them. If you lead with that info, then I'll accept this answer

Comment: @ZoltanDeWitt Ok, I reworded it a bit.